# PHP mySQL - How do i print only different attributes of two things that share a common name?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, loops, while-loop

I'm trying to print out a list of products on a page. This is cake so far..
However Some of my items share names but have different attributes. 
Example would be like...:

```
product:

keyboard
keyboard

size:

25 inches
23 inches

color:

red
blue
```

My table looks something like this:
id, product, size, color, so on...

So my .php I'm doing my query and print from looks something like this

```
<div id="accordion">
<?php
$letter = $_GET['letter'];
//echo "$id";
include("database.php");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT UPPER(product) AS upperName, PRODUCTS.* FROM PRODUCTS WHERE product LIKE '$letter%' ORDER BY UPPER(product) ");

$prodName = "";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    if ($row['upperName'] != $prodName)
    {
        print('<div style="background-color:#666; padding-bottom:25px; margin-bottom:25px;">');
        print ("<h1>" . "$row[product]" . "</h1>");
    }

        print ("$row[ndc]" . "<br />");
        print ("$row[size]" . "<br />");
        print ("$row[strength]" . "<br />");
        print ("$row[imprint]" . "<br />");
        print ("$row[form]" . "<br />");
        print ("$row[color]" . "<br />");

        print('</div>');
    $prodName = $row['upperName'];  


}
mysql_close($linkID);

?>
</div>
```

My problem comes from trying to style the attributes..

Do you see that /div tag?
I want to style that stuff within an accordion however that stuff repeats for each product that shares the same name in that accordion. So if i include the div there, it prints out for 3 times with the same name 3 end div tags (hence breaking all my html nooo!!)

Is there a way to maybe loop? or use some kind of conditional logic to print that top stuff, once for the product name that all the products share, then the loop and print all the different attributes, then when each attribute is finished, to then include my closing html?

So if i have 6 products and half are named "keyboard", and the other half are named "shoes"
could i get it to print out
TABLE
product name: KEYBOARD
table for all my attributes
end table for all my attributes
end TABLE

TABLE
product name: SHOES
table for all my attributes
end table for all my attributes
end TABLE

That way i can style all my attributes.
I'm really sorry if this isn't correctly explained I'm still learning.
Any help is appreciated!

---

Extra stuff that you may not need to figure out my problem just an example of a table i'm printing to and why the way the attributes print is a problem. the 1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9 are data for the attributes.

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="649">
    <tr>
        <td width="180" height="10" valign="top"></td><td width="36" height="10" valign="top"></td><td width="433" height="10" valign="top"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="180" valign="top"><img src="images/slide1.gif" width="180" height="200" border="0" /></td>
        <td width="36" valign="top"></td>
        <td width="433" valign="top"><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="433">
            <tr>
                <td valign="top"><span class="in-table-head">Name:</span></td>
                <td valign="top"><span class="in-table-name">$row[name]</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td valign="top"><span class="in-table-head">Therapeutic Category:</span></td>
                <td valign="top"><span class="in-table-name">$row[therapeutic]</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" valign="top"><span class="in-table-providers">Information for Providers</span></td>
            </tr>
        </table></td>
    </tr></table>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="649">
    <tr>
        <td><span class="in-table-att">NDC#:</span></td>
        <td><span class="in-table-att">Strength:</span></td>
        <td><span class="in-table-att">Size:</span></td>
        <td><span class="in-table-att">Imprint:</span></td>
        <td><span class="in-table-att">Form:</span></td>
        <td><span class="in-table-att">Color:</span></td>
        <td><span class="in-table-att">Shape:</span></td>
        <td><span class="in-table-att">Pack Size:</span></td>
        <td><span class="in-table-att">Rating:</span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="649">
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Thank you again to anyone who looks at this problem!

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [*red box*](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: Thank you for the info. I will look into it. Sorry i'm very novice and still have so much to learn :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

stop matching by name but start using sku’s as a selector. that way you’re always spot on, no matter how many keyboards you have.
set up your pages to pass the sku instead of generic name.

otherwise you need to add more criteria to your where statement like dimensions, weight, color, price etc... to get ta reliable result.

-- Update --

An example.

page.php?product_type=keyboard

```
<?php
// set up database
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "pass", "database_name");
// Just using mysql escape string, you should consider adding more securty checking to prevent injection
$producttype = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['product_type']);
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `products`.`type`='$producttype'");
$features["width"][]
$features["height"][]
$features["color"][]
$features["whatever"][]
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
    $features["width"][] = $row["width"];
    $features["height"][] = $row["height"];
    $features["color"][] = $row["color"];
    $features["whatever"][] = $row["whatever"];
    }
// printing the features
echo "You have selected $producttype<BR>";
echo "The following widths can be selected<BR><UL>";
foreach($features["width"] as $width)
    echo "<LI>$width</lI>";
echo "</UL><P>The following heights can be selected<BR><UL>";
foreach($features["heights"] as $height)
echo "<LI>$height</lI>";
    echo "</UL><P>The following colors can be selected<BR><UL>";
foreach($features["colors"] as $color)
    echo "<LI>$color</lI>";
echo "</UL><P>The following whatevers can be selected<BR><UL>";
foreach($features["whatevers"] as $whatevers)
    echo "<LI>$whatevers</lI>";
echo "</UL>";
echo "have a nice day";
?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for replying!
SKU do you mean? Stock-keeping unit?
Yes that would make sense to get products by this.
My problem does not come from getting my info. It comes from printing out only info that is different between products.
I can print it out. I can get product names that they share, i can get all product values, but i want to only print out product name once, then all the different attributes. because i have no way of closing out my html after each set of attributes for products that have the same name. - sorry if i'm not making sense :( i really appreciate the help!

Comment: Now i know what you mean. You need to first make a ’static version’ of the end result, what you want the result to be and make sure its functional eith the static demo values. when that works start replacing the static code with dynamic database values. you’ll discover then what chunks of code can be placed in a foreach loop so you get dynamic sizing of your accordeon. does this make sense to you?

Comment: i have a working version the static html, and dynamic.
http://www.agencystudy.com/her/products.php
-click view all-
my trouble comes when i try to combine the attributes for products with the same name, I don't understand enough to write two lopps (which i think is what i need) since i want to loop for each product name, then for all the attributes that same product names share.
:/

Comment: Well, first off use in your menu css list-style:none; to get rid of the bullets.
I'm going to update my answer now.

Comment: Thank you so much Michael! I'm still working on it. But thank you so much for helping out so much.

Comment: You’re welcome! Always happy to help someone on his way. If i was help enough you could consider green checking me :-)